# Printing PDF file doesn't work on a random basis

Tags: 12.04, printing, epson

I have tried printing from Chrome, Firefox and Document viewer. On a random basis (means 20 papers go fine, 1 doesn't, 1 does, 2 don't, etc) instead of the file I sent to be printed, I get this:

[image]

It has never showed any errors except out of paper/bad paper size (warning, seems to be wrong) on the printer. I'm using Epson EPL-n3000 printer connected through USB. Same thing occurs on multiple computers, every one using the same printer and Ubuntu version.

I have tried changing some printer settings, including paper size and paper source (cassete/tray), getting the same result.

Re-downloading and updating as needed `poppler-utils` and `cups` packages from precise-updates, again the same. Test pages and printing to file both seem to be working fine; but I can't be sure because the whole problem seems to be occuring randomly (it never failed though).

It seems that when I wait for an approx. 5 min, the next page is always printed fine. However, I need to be able to print more than 100 pages without stopping.

It's important to notice that I don't currently have access to that printer (it's at work), nor the documents (it's on the network at work), so I'll try every solution and workaround on Monday.

--

**I think I've figured out what's the problem:**
I have tried installing PPD file - doesn't work.
Printing test pages - doesn't work (for the first time)
Printing self-test pages - works!
I'll write this off as a CUPS bug and will research a little more and report it shortly. If anyone has any other idea, please tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing but it may be a bug with the drivers. I had similar driver problems with my networked Epson XP-200 and the problems seemed to disappear over time (and updates), but also seemed to be computer dependent - some ubuntu 12.04 machines did fine while others failed sometimes, only difference being the computer hardware.

Looking at [this page](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-EPL-N3000) your printer seems to have full Debian support, which would mean it would work under Ubuntu. Maybe reinstall the driver manually? There is a .deb file listed there that Ubuntu Software Center would take, probably an installer for the PPD file.

I would think that if the PPD file doesn't work that the print test wouldn't work.

Have fun fidiling around. Just thought I'd add some input.

Comment: I've tried installing PPD, both by running a .run file from Epson's site and getting the PPD file manually. The randomness of the printing confuses me, everything doesn't work only on occasion. Printing test pages used to work every time previously, but 2 days ago I started getting the papers in the image printed and couldn't print normal test page anymore (no changes were made). And the same thing happens with 3 computers with the same printer and software, but different hardware.

Comment: Also, I've replaced those printers with the HP ones which work normally, and put Epson ones on the Windows XP computers (the reason I hesitated to do that was because Ubuntu computers are heavily used, and I have only some old HP printers which are quite slow). That means I can't fiddle around so much anymore, only if I'm sure I have the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see a fellow *nix user with a similar issue, although mine is blank pages and pages with images only.

I have been advised that Epson do have Linux drivers, I have a cheap n cheerful D92.

Maybe a walk over to Epson might be in order.